# Script/Tool to Auto Hide/Unhide Windows Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have to toggle Windows taskbar auto hide/unhide frequently. Is there any way (eg via script, registry or tool) that can let me simply double click to toggle the setting?

Comment: I'm curious, why do frequently have to toggle the `Auto hide taskbar` setting? What part of your work necessitates sometimes having it *usually hidden* for some of your day, and *always visible* for other parts of your day?

Comment: @WalterStabosz Screensharing when presenting during teleconferences is a common use case.  For example, a software salesperson who does online screen-sharing demos (showing integration/interaction between multiple applications) with remote prospective customers might prefer the taskbar be autohidden for those portions of the day but visible during the rest.

Comment: @WBT Thanks, I had never considered frequent screen sharing. Rereading this question made me think of a UI design for a nice auto-hidden **Taskbar**:  Press `Windows Key` once to unhide **Taskbar**, press `Windows Key` a second time to open **Start Menu**. You could also double-press `Windows Key` to open **Start Menu**.

Comment: @WalterStabosz Win+T can do the unhide and switch between programs on it.  However, it'd be nice to have a little script connected to a keyboard shortcut that just toggles this one setting value.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **[Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator)**.

I heard it is a good one.

Comment: this tool is nice, thanks! However, the hotkey Alt+T can be easily conflict with many other applications. Also, it hide the taskbar completely, not toggle to auto hide.

Comment: If this is still relevant for anyone, I posted an answer with a software that let's you choose your own hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com) script for showing/hiding the taskbar (or compile it to executable(s) with so you can run this without needing AutoIt)

This example script hides the taskbar, sleeps 3 seconds and shows the taskbar:

```
Opt('WINTITLEMATCHMODE', 4)
ControlHide('classname=Shell_TrayWnd', '', '')
Sleep(3000)
ControlShow('classname=Shell_TrayWnd', '', '')
```

The script has been taken from: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/27505-hide-taskbar/

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses AutoHotkey:

[How to toggle the auto-hide status of the Windows taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/654170/how-to-toggle-the-auto-hide-status-of-the-windows-taskbar/656145#656145)

You can set it to whatever key combination you need.

Answer (score 1):

I recently went looking for exactly this and ultimately made my own as the existing stuff either doesn't work well or at all. Here's [a tool that toggles hide taskbar](https://github.com/gfody/ToggleTaskbar) with source.

Comment: Thank you, finally an open source tool that does this!  I hoped it could be a simple PowerShell script, but it seems [the corresponding registry key](https://winbuzzer.com/2021/03/19/how-to-hide-or-unhide-the-taskbar-in-windows-10-auto-hide-xcxwbt/#How_to_Turn_Auto-Hide_Taskbar_On_or_Off_via_Registry_Editor) is a little more complex 

Comment: Turns out **there is one**  | See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1266914/316320) to almost a duplicate question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave it hidden and use instead:

http://rocketdock.com/

http://rocketdock.com/Help/English/#hotkeys-disable
(ctrl-alt-r)

http://rocketdock.com/Help/English/#settings-behavior
http://rocketdock.com/Help/English/#settings-position
http://rocketdock.com/Help/English/#quick-access-to-options

Answer (score 0):

I found something called [Taskbar Eliminator](http://www.askvg.com/taskbar-eliminator-hide-remove-windows-taskbar/) via Google that sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: CAREFULL: the other software (Windows Taskbar Hide) that can be found under the link does not work with Windows 7!! It will "hide" your taskbar but "unhiding" does not work - that resulted in a LOSS OF DATA for me!

Comment: glad I could help, I would even suggest to write it into the answer since not all users read the comments.

Comment: @Albin: I'm still using Windows 7, so can't confirm or deny what you claim. Your comment is not about the software I mentioned, plus, just because you had a bad experience is not enough evidence IMO for me feel comfortable issuing a blanket warning. Also, down here in a comment is exactly the right place for information like that to be put.

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure where to put the warning, thanks for the explanation. By the way I'm using Windows 7 as well, so I might get the same error if you decide to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but I just stumbled upon another software alternative (freeware, no installation required): [Taskbar Control](https://www.thefreewindows.com/3252/hide-completely-the-windows-taskbar-using-a-hotkey-and-unhide-it-with-taskbar-control/) here's the [download link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TheFreeWindows-Taskbar-Control.shtml)

It's no double click as the question requires but it let's you toggle the auto hide by using a hotkey and it lets you decide on you're own choice of hotkey.

I tested it with Windows 7, works for me (and I keep it), maybe this helps s.o. else as well. There is also a Version for Windows 10 but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode", you can use the following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to toggle the taskbar with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
  #j::Send !{Esc}
#IfWinActive
  #j::WinActivate ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
#IfWinActive
```